# How to skip a revision in svn repository

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

So say I have the three latest revisions of an aspx file: 55, 56 and 57.
Revision 56 added a feature that I want to remove, but I also want to have the new features deployed in version 57.  Is there any way I can merge version 55 with 57, leaving revision 56 out of the picture?

If it matters, I'm using Tortoise SVN and Visual SVN, but I normally just use Tortoise.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I'm following your question, it sounds like you want r57 minus r56.  (i.e. including changes from r55 to r0)

**command-line:**

```
svn merge <path_to_repo> . -c -56
```

**Tortoise**:
Show Log / Right-click revision 56 and select "Revert changes from this revision"

Answer (score 3):

Show the log for that file.
Select revisions 55 and 57 (hold down the ctrl key for multi-selection).
Right-click, choose "revert changes from these revisions".
then commit.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can "skip a revision". Keep in mind that Subversion stores all this data as a series of diffs, and leaving out one revision would render SVN clueless as to how to apply the following one. You can create a patch that undoes whatever was done in revision 56. Just run

```
svn up
svn diff -r 55:56 > /tmp/r56.patch
patch -p1 < /tmp/r56.patch
svn -m "Undo changes from revision 56."
```